# Spring + Hibernate: HQL dentro de transacción ejecuta commit

Tags: spring, hibernate, transacciones, hql

Tengo una aplicación en la que se llama a un método anotado con @Transactional REQUIRED_NEW. Dentro del mismo, en un punto, se llama a un DAO que ejecuta un HQL con executeUpdate. Al volver al método inicial, en BBDD se ha persistido ese Update aunque la transacción no ha terminado ya que no he salido del método transaccional. ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se persista ese update?

Comment: Deberías agregar un ejemplo de tu código, para tener una mejor idea del problema

Answer (score 0):

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void xxxxxxxx(A b) throws Exception {

List lista= new ArrayList<>();
            lista.add("1234567890");

```
        StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
        hql.append("UPDATE C np SET np.estado.codigo = :codigoEstado, fechaModificacion = sysdate, dato= :dato, inicio= sysdate, final= null,duracion= null    WHERE np.numero IN (:pNumeros )");

        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
        query.setParameterList("pNumeros", lista);
        query.setParameter("codigoEstado", 1);
        query.setParameter("dato", 'aaa');

        query.executeUpdate();
```

LOGGER.info("buahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
}

Hciendo debug. cuando llega al log en BBDD ya se ha realizado el commit.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes, por favor su ayuda el tema es que cada vez que trato de hacer un Update usando Spring con Hibernate3 me sale el error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not
>   supported for DML operations [UPDATE

Intente de varias formas dentro de una clase GenericDaoHibernateImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport  implements GenericDaoHibernate:

```
public void findByCriterio3(String namedQuery, String[] paramNames, Object[] values) 
                        this.getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(namedQuery, paramNames, values);

Donde @NamedQuery(name = "TCreditos.updateVEstadoCredito", query = "UPDATE TCreditos t SET t.vEstadoCredito = :vEstadoCredito WHERE t.nIdCreditoPk = :nIdCreditoPk")



StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
 hql.append("UPDATE TCreditos t SET t.vEstadoCredito = :vEstadoCredito WHERE t.nIdCreditoPk = :nIdCreditoPk");
Query query = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
 query.setParameter("vEstadoCredito", a);
 query.setParameter("nIdCreditoPk",c );
 query.executeUpdate();
```